# 90s (or earlier) scifi/apocalyptic novel: group waking up in an old school, female lead character has an electric connection with her lover

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I read this sci-fi/apocalyptic novel when I was in my early teen years. The main character was a female and there were several others and it's like they woke up or found themselves abandoned in an old school or something. I believe there was some kind of war going on or maybe they were trapped in a different time or dimension.

What I remember the most is this female falls in love with a guy she meets and they have this instant electric connection when they look at each other or when their hands touch. This connection reminds her about of a previous experience in her life. They end up kissing, and she feels this electric wave and these flashbacks.

I know this sounds completely crazy. I am now in my mid-thirties and I am just trying to figure out what this book was. I do not believe it was a series because if it had been I would have read the whole series.

Comment: Most of the details you have given are quite broad: girl/boy meets someone in an unusual setting, they instantly connect due to some forgotten past, etc, etc, is a [common trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReincarnationRomance). Could you add any more details? Perhaps what they did? More about the war or whatever?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)